# Apply() function, how does it work and where I am wrong?

Tags: r

I need to convert with str_split a big data_frame. The idea is to check if the value in 2 columns is `!= 0` and is so, split them on `"_"` in new columns. I want to keep the new values in 3 new different columns. I was thinking of a for loop, but it will take forever and I wanted to use `apply()`, but is not working.

the data.frame is:

```
a <- structure(list(seqnames1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1",  "chr1",
"chr1"), start1 = c(4207675L, 4207675L, 4207675L, 4207675L,  4207675L,
4207675L), end1 = c(4207887L, 4207887L, 4207887L, 4207887L,  4207887L,
4207887L), width1 = c(213L, 213L, 213L, 213L, 213L,  213L), strand1 =
c("*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"), node.class1 = c("bait",  "bait",
"bait", "bait", "bait", "bait"), promoter.id1 = c(0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L), promoter_flanking_region.id1 = c(0L, 0L,  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
exon.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), intron.id1 = c(0L,  0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L), enhancer.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    fli1.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gata1.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gata2.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tal1.id1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ctcf.id1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    bait.id1 = c("chr1:4267838-4267939", "chr1:4267838-4267939", 
    "chr1:4267838-4267939", "chr1:4267838-4267939", "chr1:4267838-4267939", 
    "chr1:4267838-4267939"), gene_name.id1 = c("0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0"), RNA_expression.id1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0"), seqnames2 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
    "chr1", "chr1"), start2 = c(1886952L, 2562429L, 2908853L, 
    3596298L, 4008510L, 4025732L), end2 = c(1887558L, 2562819L, 
    2909055L, 3597281L, 4008863L, 4026507L), width2 = c(607L, 
    391L, 203L, 984L, 354L, 776L), strand2 = c("*", "*", "*", 
    "*", "*", "*"), node.class2 = c("intron", "exon", "intergenic_region", 
    "intron", "promoter_flanking_region", "promoter_flanking_region"
    ), promoter.id2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), promoter_flanking_region.id2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), exon.id2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    intron.id2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), enhancer.id2 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fli1.id2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    gata1.id2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gata2.id2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tal1.id2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    ctcf.id2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), bait.id2 = c("0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), gene_name.id2 = c("GNB1_21665", "TNFRSF14_25838", 
    "0", "MEGF6_34434", "AL805961.1_25459", "0"), RNA_expression.id2 = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), counts = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), CHiCAGO_Score = c(0.57, 1.39, 1.78, 3.26, 3.52, 3.48
    ), distance_bait_prey = c(2320526, 1645157, 1298827, 610991, 
    199094, 181661), RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id1 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), RNA_expression_logFPKM_id1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), RNA_expression_stratification_id1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    RNA_expression_logFPKM_id2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RNA_expression_stratification_id2 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table",  "data.frame"))
```

My (nonreproducible) code to import the data.frame and start the new columns at zero

```
a <- data.table::fread(input='file',  sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
a$RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id1 <- "0"
a$RNA_expression_logFPKM_id1 <- "0"
a$RNA_expression_stratification_id1 <- "0"
a$RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id2 <- "0"
a$RNA_expression_logFPKM_id2 <- "0"
a$RNA_expression_stratification_id2 <- "0"
```

The for loop i had in mind

```
for ( i in seq(1, length(a$gene_name.id1))){
        if (a$RNA_expression.id1[i] != 0){
                b <- str_split(a$RNA_expression.id1[i], "_", n=3)
                a$RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id1[i] <- b[[1]][1]
                a$RNA_expression_logFPKM_id1[i] <- b[[1]][2]
                a$RNA_expression_stratification_id1[i] <- b[[1]][3]
                }
        if (a$RNA_expression.id2[i] != 0){
                b <- str_split(a$RNA_expression.id1[i], "_", n=3)
                a$RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id1[i] <- b[[1]][1]
                a$RNA_expression_logFPKM_id1[i] <- b[[1]][2]
               a$RNA_expression_stratification_id1[i] <- b[[1]][3]
                }
}
```

I tried to create a function to use `apply()` as follow:

```
my_function <- function(a){
        if (a[19] != 0){
                b <- str_split(a[19], "_", n=3)
                a[43] <- b[[1]][1]
                a[44] <- b[[1]][2]
                a[45] <- b[[1]][3]
                }
        if (a[19] != 0){
               b <- str_split(a[38], "_", n=3)
                a[46] <- b[[1]][1]
                a[47] <- b[[1]][2]
                a[48] <- b[[1]][3]
                }
}`

apply(a, 1, my_function)
```

I am getting a list of `NULL` values and only the last of the three values I am splitting 
Where am I wrong? am I completely off with the structure of the script?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(a))`, and what you expect the output to look like (even if manually typed).

Comment: How can I correctly format the data.frame?

Comment: (1) 47 columns is a bit much, can you reduce your sample data to be only a few relevant columns? (2) What is your intended output? (BTW: minor nit, but when you post the output from `dput` of a `data.table`, please remove the `.internal.selfref`, it cannot be used outside of your immediate R session and does not harm things when missing here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `apply` expects a matrix as input, as you are providing a data.frame the first thing that `apply` does is coercing your data.frame, hence changing all columns to the same type and messing everything. Another problems is that `apply` returns an array or list of values which is not the output you expect (a data.frame/data.table).

You could achieve the same result with `separate` from `tidyr`. For example, the `id1` case:

```
  separate(a,
           RNA_expression.id1, 
           into = c("RNA_expression_gene_symbol_id1", 
                    "RNA_expression_logFPKM_id1",
                    "RNA_expression_stratification_id1"), 
           sep = "_",
           fill = "left")
```